# Converting java object to an InputStream (for uploading to S3) with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a POJO that I was going to serialize to .json and upload to S3. Bit. it turns out that since I use a writer to write (i.e. serialize) the .json to disk before I upload it, this doesn't work, as I don't have write permissions to the directory that java would use to write the file to disk before it uploads.

I could use a TempFile, but is there a simple way to convert a java object to an InputStream so I can use the corresponding S3Client inputStream `putObject` method instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of different methods which you can use to serialize objects to `JSON` in `Jackson` library. For example: [`byte[] writeValueAsBytes(Object value)`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsBytes(java.lang.Object)).

See also:

1. [String writeValueAsString(Object value)](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#writeValueAsString(java.lang.Object))